# Yii2 Asset Convertor

Tags: php, less, yii2

I'm trying to use Less with my Yii2 application.
I use the advanced application and would like to convert my .less files in the frontend/web/css using the asset convertor build in with yii2.

```
'assetManager' => [
      'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [                     
                 'css' => []
            ],

        ],
     'converter' => [
         'class' => 'yii\web\AssetConverter',
         'commands' => [
            'less' => ['css', 'lessc {from} {to} --no-color'],

         ],
        ],
    ],
```

The above is in my main.php config file.

```
    class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.less',
       'css/superhero.less',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

The above is the appAsset file.

but how can I install the less tool in my yii2 installation? I put less-1.7.5.js in the root folder where my yii console bootstrap file is but where do I have to adjust the configuration to convert the less files?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've just did in my project:

main.php config file:

```
    'assetManager' => [
        'converter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\AssetConverter',
            'commands' => [
                'less' => ['css', 'nodejs "' . PROTECTED_BASE_PATH . 
                    '/node_modules/less/bin/lessc" {from} {to} --no-color'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Command line (in the subdirectory, represented by PROTECTED_BASE_PATH above):

```
$ npm install less
```

That's all. It works fine after git pull on another machine.

Of course, nodejs itself must be installed globally.

**Important note.** This is unusual way to keep the nodejs packges in VCS (though I have a reason to do so). Consider use of package.json instead.

Answer (score 1):

To install less compiler (lessc) to your project use composer command:

```
composer require bower-asset/less
```

Then add to config:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'converter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetConverter',
        'commands' => [
            'less' => ['css', '@bower/less/packages/less/bin/lessc {from} {to} --no-color'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

This config is helpful for shared hosting, when you have no root privileges and can't install lessc globally.

Comment: Changed above path to:  @bower/less/packages/less/bin/lessc and this worked for me on my Wampserver. Testing Yiipowered. Thanks Anton.

Answer (score 0):

install less converter: Server-Side and Command Line Usage
http://lesscss.org/usage/

and make sure command available as lessc from anywhere i.e. added to PATH